# Displaying or Hiding a div depending on screen resolution

Tags: html, css, resolution

To make this short and simple, I have a `<div>` in which I wish to be hidden if the user's resolution is 1024x768.

So if I have a separate CSS file for the css left_bar, then the template with `<div id='left_bar'>` how would I go about having the resolution check query?

Answer (score 3):

```
@media all and (width:1024px) and (height:768px) {
    /* CSS rules here */
}
```

Although, that's awfully specific. Usually you use media queries with `min-width` or similar.

Comment: Since I'm self taught I have some gaps in my knowledge but what I tried was this. http://pastebin.com/Hh93Pb42 Can you explain what I've done wrong?

Comment: You mean apart from trying to define styles for a ***twenty thousand*** pixel square display?

Comment: Haha that was a test, though I guess it won't read it if I do that?

Comment: Most probably not. Try using more realistic sizes.

Comment: I tried 1600x1200 which is 4:3 yet the side bar still appears for me (I use 1280x760). So I'm thinking I've done something wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Actually it hides the CSS but not the content within the div. Here's the div and content in it - http://pastebin.com/u6DHHi6a